# Why do i have to put name for each object in FireBase data structure?

Tags: json, database, firebase

Lets take a look at google example for simple array

```
 "chats": {
    "one": {
      "title": "Historical Tech Pioneers",
      "lastMessage": "ghopper: Relay malfunction found. Cause: moth.",
      "timestamp": 1459361875666
    },
    "two": { ... },
    "three": { ... }
  },
```

My question is why do we have to put name for each chat ? if i want to add another object i need to know which are the existing keys and create new one for which reason ? i just want a list of chats in this example and the names one two three means nothing to me...

why cant i put a list of objects with no name under chats ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"chats": {
    "one": {
      "title": "Historical Tech Pioneers",
      "lastMessage": "ghopper: Relay malfunction found. Cause: moth.",
       "timestamp": 1459361875666
},
"two": { ... },
"three": { ... }
},
```

Instead of `one, two and three`, you can use `random ids` using the `push()` method in android, so you will have something like this:-

```
   "chats": {
     "id_1": {
      "title": "Historical Tech Pioneers",
      "lastMessage": "ghopper: Relay malfunction found. Cause: moth.",
      "timestamp": 1459361875666
   },
     "id_2": { ... },
     "id_3": { ... }
     },
```

You can retrieve the key like this:-

```
String mGroupId = mGroupRef.push().getKey();
```

You can think of the `ids` as primary key